# parameters to make a QR code that Authy understands

Tags: qr-code, google-authenticator

I´m about to introduce 2FA and use [QRcode.js](https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/) to generate a QR code from the secret key to be scanned by the 2FA apps.

```javascript
$('#totpQR').empty();
new QRCode(document.getElementById('totpQR'),secretkey);
$('#totpQRContainer').css('display','inline');
$('#totpQR').attr('title', 'otpauth://totp/'+encodeURIComponent(username)
    + location.hostname.replace(/^(.*\.)?(\b[\w-]+\.[a-z]+)$/, '@$2?secret=')
    + secretkey
);
```

Both GoogleAuthenticator and Authy seem to be picky there; they reject the code saying "The QR code is invalid" or similar. When I use a proper QR reader to scan the same QR, the key from the URL (`otpauth://totp/username@sitename.tld?secret=secretkey` or `otpauth://totp/sitename?secret=secretkey` or `otpauth://totp/username@sitename.tld?secret=secretkey&digits=6&issuer=SiteName&period=30`) comes out correct.

Googling for the issue gave me no results.

Can anyone tell me what parameters I should use to generate my QR or do I have to experiment?

I guess that there´s no mistake in the URL?

Comment: Did you url_encoded your data before including them in your QRcode? Can you show us le code you used with QRcode.js?

Comment: @Veve added `encodeURI` to the QR generation, but it didn´t help. Will add my JS in a moment.

Comment: @Veve Thanks. The problem was that I created the QR from the key only, not the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my code indeed: I created the QR from the key, not from the whole URL:

```javascript
$('#totpQR').empty();
var url='otpauth://totp/'+encodeURIComponent(username)
    + location.hostname.replace(/^(.*\.)?(\b[\w-]+\.[a-z]+)$/, '@$2?secret=')
    + secretkey
;
new QRCode(document.getElementById('totpQR'),url);
$('#totpQRContainer').css('display','inline');
$('#totpQR').attr('title',url);
```

Comment: @Veve I´ll accept this in two days; can´t be done any sooner. Didn´t know it would keep showing up after being deleted.